# Purpose of "initial" state in MongoDB two phase commits

Tags: mongodb

Referencing [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) about performing two-phase commits with MongoDB:

What is the purpose of the "initial" state of the transaction?  Why wouldn't you just insert your transaction document with a "pending" state and save a round trip to the database?

Comment: `initial` denotes a transaction who is not yet running while `pending` denotes a transaction that is. It is about which transactions you need to rollback in the even of a fail for whatever reason and exactly what you need to do to rollback them back, if you don't need to rollback initial transactions on a busy system then you can save some load.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one applications running the same transaction, as explained later in [the article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#multiple-applications), "initial" state basically means that logical lock is free, so findAndModify() could update the document to get that lock. Thus only one application is allowed to run the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a good reason for the initial state: The 2PC protocol defines a state machine with an 'initial' state, which transitions to 'pending'. The transaction should only be in 'pending' state once all participants are in pending state. In addition the transition to 'commit' should only be started when the transaction is in 'pending' state. Finally the transaction should only be marked as 'committed' once all participants have successfully committed.

If you started the transition to commit without fully reaching the pending state, you risk breaking the atomicity and isolation guarantees.

In the article referenced the transaction state is changed to pending before setting the participants to pending (inserting the records). The transaction state is set to committed before committing the participants. And there is an extra state called 'done', this might lead to bugs in the coordinator implementation. I suggest you take the article with a grain of salt.